# Java Connect four method full board

Tags: java, methods

okay so what I have to do is make a java connect four game. One of the methods which is named full is used to check if the board is full or not. If it is it returns true, if not then it returns false. White is used for empty spaces. The problem is I can't compare board and Color.White and I don't know what to do from here. My code is below

```
public static boolean full(Color[][] board) {
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        if (board != Color.WHITE){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to do something with that variable you're iterating over. As is, you're just comparing whether the two-dimensional array itself is equal to what I assume is an enum value, (and doing so `board.length` times) which, of course, will never be true.

Comment: What's "in" board is what you want to compare, not `board` iteself

Comment: So would I check every position in the board then? Another way I was thinking is just checking the topmost row of the board and if none of those return white then making it true. Is that doable?

Comment: Yeah, in the case of Connect Four, where pieces fall down, just checking the top row would suffice I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say with only the snippet of code. What kind of object is 'board'?
To me it seems like you should increment through the Color[][] array in a double for-loop and see if any of the elements are equal to Color.WHITE.

```
public static boolean full(Color[][] board) {
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<board.length;j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == Color.WHITE){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any logs, error messages, or print statements to help debug? Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like you can fix this to just check the top row, instead of every position.

Comment: with the code above it tells me that Color cannot be resolved to a variable. Do i need to create one in the method

Comment: What exactly is Color[][]? ArrayList, String array or is it its own defined object? Can you post the code where you instantiate the Color[][] object?

Comment: Color[][] board = new Color[ROWS][COLUMNS];

Comment: Oh, so it sounds like you need to do board[i][j] in place of Color[][]. My bad, I should have caught that.